# Null Pointer Exception for LayoutInflater inflater and ViewGroup container

Tags: java, android, variables, initialization, parameter-passing

I am making an app that creates an ImageButton every time the user does a certain action. So my button creation in dynamic.

I have a method (createButton) inside a FRAGMENT class that gets passed an image (which is used as the background of my ImageButton).

My problem is that I seem to need to use "LayoutInflater inflate" and "ViewGroup container" in order to open my relative layout view and add a dynamic button to it, but I am also passing an image this method, so my method is forcing me to initialize inflate and container.

I can't initialize them to null because then I get a NullPointerException when I run my app. I also try to pass them from onCreateView (like my code below), but I still get a NullPointerException. **How can I use LayoutInflater inflate and ViewGroup container (without initializing them to null) while still passing other variables to my method.** I am getting thrown the exception before "tag-name: rLayout" gets printed.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

ViewGroup rootContainer;
LayoutInflater rootInflater;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

// onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);


    rootContainer = container;

    rootInflater = inflater;

    return view;
}



// Create button from icon and image name

public void createButton (BitmapDrawable bitmapdrawable, String applicationName){

    Log.d("tag_name", "createButton");

    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService
            //(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    try {


        Log.d("tag_name", "Try_2");

        // Get Layout home_fragment
        View rootView = rootInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, rootContainer, false);
        RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_fragment);
        Log.d("tag_name", "rLayout");

        // create image button with background as bitmapdrawable
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(getActivity());
        btn.setImageDrawable(bitmapdrawable);
        int id = 1;
        btn.setId(id);
        Log.d("tag_name", "set the ID of the btn");

        // create textview with applicationName
        //TextView appName = new TextView(getActivity());
        //appName.setText(applicationName);

        // place new button next to existing button
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);

        // place text under newly created button


        // Put button and text in layout
        rLayout.addView(btn);
        //rLayout.addView(appName);
    }

    catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println("Exception is "+e.toString());
    }

}

}
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/tag_name: createButton
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus D/tag_name: Try_2
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus I/System.out: Exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus W/System.err:     at it.anddev.bradipao.janus.HomeFragment.createButton(HomeFragment.java:118)
05-03 14:33:42.468 7197-7223/it.anddev.bradipao.janus W/System.err:     at it.anddev.bradipao.janus.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:155)
```

The line 118 in HomeFragment is this line:

```
View rootView = rootInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, rootContainer, false);
```

The line 155 in my mainActivity is the second line here where I pass my variables to HomeFragment:

```
HomeFragment createbutton = new HomeFragment();
createbutton.createButton(bitmapdrawable, applicationName);
```

Comment: I don't understand why passing inflator and container is even required? Your method accepts a BitmapDrawable, the other two variables don't need to be passed, you are already declaring inflator inside your createButton. Contdainer is also not needed, you can use null.

Comment: @varunkr when I make container null (like I do in my code posted), I get an exception thrown "NullPointerException".

Comment: I don't think a null pointer should be thrown though passing null in container is not always a good thing. Since all this is happening inside a fragment you can try passing fragment's root as the container. Should work !!

Comment: @varunkr what do you mean by pass the fragment's root as the container?

Comment: You must be overriding onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) inside your fragment, right? Just use the container value from here, this container defines the root of your fragment. See if that works, I am not 100% sure but I think it should work

Comment: @varunkr You are correct that my fragment also contains onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState). So I tried to grab the variable container by adding this line to my createButton method: 
        ViewGroup container = onCreateView(container); but it still gives the error "container might not have been initialized"

Comment: Please have a look at my answer, onCreateView(container) is not even a valid method, not sure how that compiled.

Comment: ok, i will try it myself !!

Comment: @varunkr any luck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110933/discussion-between-varunkr-and-natalie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you create the fragment and call the createButton method over it

```
HomeFragment createbutton = new HomeFragment();
createbutton.createButton(bitmapdrawable, applicationName);
```

You cannot do this. All Activities, Fragments and Services in Android must go through their respective lifecycle so that they have a valid context attached to them.

By treating them as a normal Java class, you end up with a null context. As most methods in an Activity, fragments or service are called on its Context, you will get a null pointer exception, which is why your app crashes.

What you need !!

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
Fragment profileFragment = new HomeFragment();//the fragment you want to show
fragmentTransaction
        .add(R.id.parent, profileFragment);//R.id.content_frame is the layout you want to replace
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This is how you create your fragment.

And for caling its createButton method you need an interface.

You will need to create an interface like this in you Fragment

```
public interface ButtonCreator{
    void buttonCreator(BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable, String string);
}
```

And in your activity you will need to implement this method. Like this:

```
@Override
public void buttonCreator(BitmapDrawable bitmap,String a) {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
    homeFragment.createButton(bitmap,a);
}
```

Don't forget to implement the interface like this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MenuFragment.OnMenufragListener, HomeFragment.ButtonCreator {
```

Also in your fragment you will have to get this in your onAttach method

```
private ButtonCreator bc;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    bc = (ButtonCreator) activity;
}
```

And you will call

```
buttonCreator(bitmapdrawable, applicationName);
```

instaed of

```
createbutton.createButton(bitmapdrawable, applicationName);
```

This will work. However I also see an error in your button implementation.

You will have to look into it.

```
  btn.setId(id);
```

Above line needs an id like `R.id.something` , not an integer. I am sure you will solve that.

Comment: I really was hoping that this would work, because I have seen it work for others as I look through the internet, but I am still getting a NullPointerException. I have updated my question to show all my code as of now.

Comment: Can you also post your stack trace, that would be helpful, it is strange how a null pointer can be thrown now !

Comment: RRRRGGG, Now I am getting a NullPointerException at rLayout.addView(btn) in createButton method...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110940/discussion-between-varunkr-and-natalie).